# Method 1 is executing,but Method 2 is not.But they are exactly same scale transformation,just written in different forms.Why?

Tags: unity-game-engine

const float ScaleFactorPerSecond = 1;
int scaleFactorSignMultiplier = 1;

```
void Update()
{

    // resize the game object
    Vector3 newScale = transform.localScale;
    newScale.x += scaleFactorSignMultiplier * ScaleFactorPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
    newScale.y += scaleFactorSignMultiplier * ScaleFactorPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.localScale = newScale;




   

    Method-2
    newScale.x = newscale.x * scaleFactorSignMultiplier * ScaleFactorPerSecond * Time.deltatime;
    newscale.y = newscale.y * scaleFactorSignMultiplier * ScaleFactorPerSecond * Time.deltatime;
```

Comment: For method 1 you are using `+=` for method 2 you are basically using `*=` ... I suspect a typo?

Answer (score 1):

The two methods don't do exactly the same thing.
Method one newScale.X would be rewritten as:

```
newScale.x = newScale.x + (scaleFactorSignMultiplier * ScaleFactorPerSecond * Time.deltaTime);
```

while method two would be be rewritten as:

```
newScale.x *= scaleFactorSignMultiplier * ScaleFactorPerSecond * Time.deltatime;
```